# Open up a Form from a Button click?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a user control form for a countdown timer.  I want a start button to then launch the timer.  The timer will then be labels in another form.  What do I need to do to launch this new form from the click on start button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var form = new YourForm();
form.Show();
```